# Bottleneck in my recursive python code

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, cyk

I wrote the below code using recursion to do [CYK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) so that the Grammar `G` can generate any words having same number of `a`'s followed by any number of `b`'s but for some reason it is very slow, not sure why? When I use s2 it works, but if I used s1 which is a longer string it takes forever. Could anyone please advise as I can't figure out where is the bottleneck?

```
def fn(G, w, i, j, T):
    if T[i, j]:
        print '1'
        return T[i, j]
    elif i == j:
        for r in G:
            print '2'
            if r.endswith(w[i]) and r[0] not in T[i, j]:    
                print '3'
                T[i, j].append(r[0])
    else:
        print '4'
        for k in range(i, j):
            print '5'
            for a in fn(G, w, i, k, T):
                print '6'
                for b in fn(G, w, k+1, j, T):
                    print '7'
                    for r in G:
                        print '8'
                        if r.endswith(a+b) and r[0] not in T[i, j]:
                            print '9'
                            T[i, j].append(r[0])
    return T[i, j]


def fnmain(G, S, w):
    dict = {}
    for x in range(0, len(w)):
        for y in range(x, len(w)):
            dict[x,y] = []
    print dict        
    v = fn(G, w, 0, len(w) - 1, dict)
    print (w, v)
    if S in v:
        print ("T")
        return True
    else:
        print ("F")
        return False

G = ["S->AB", "S->XB", "T->AB", "T->XB", "X->AT", "A->a", "B->b"]

s1 = "aaaaabbbbb"
s1 = "aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb"

fnmain(G, "S", s1)
```

I've used `cProfile` as suggested by @wwii and below is the result:

When s1 = "aaaaabbbbb"
[image]
when s1= "aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb"
[image]

Comment: Have you [Profiled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) it??  Look for nested loops - the deeper the nesting the longer it will take.  Try to refactor.

Comment: @wwii Thank you. I've updated my question to include the cProfile results and included a screenshot of the results. If you could please advise.

Comment: In the `else` suite of `fn` , there are nested loops three deep. The two inner loops iterate over a recursive call to the same function.  It seems that the complexity is increasing exponentially.  Looking at the link you posted, the pseudocode has many nested loops - so maybe you cannot get away with it. Try to see if your solution has **more** nesting than the algorithm in the link.

Comment: Just a quick comment. There is no need to call the function `fnmain`. The `def` makes us aware that it is a function, So you can just call it `main`.

Comment: The program might get bogged down with garbage collecting. Try to avoid passing too many parameters, e.g. G could be kept in a global context.

Comment: @yacc I changed the G to be global but still very slow

Comment: Maybe there's more insight if you profile a heavy load. I mean 0.026s isn't very much.

Comment: @yacc I've updated the question modifying the input string which is a profile heavy load and updated the screenshot

Comment: I'd move G, w and T to global context and then check again. Most of the time the function checks T[i,j] and returns it since defined. That means, it's just a hell of a lot invocations.

Comment: I just noticed you had two strings s1 and s2 originally included which seem to have vanished. I suggest to update your question with a few strings and their respective processing time to illustrate the situation.

Comment: @yacc I've updated my question with two different input strings as s1.

Comment: Why is this recursive? The pseudo-code on the Wiki page doesn't look like that. Where is P?

Comment: @yacc  I already developed it normally and it works fast but now trying to make it with recursion but looks like there is something wrong that is making it too slow